# How to update route parameters in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a component which has some filtering dropdowns and a result table

I have to update the results in the table based on the combination of dropdown filters

I want to use one router parameter and a few query parameters for this

So my URL would look like this

`http://localhost:3000/dashboard/component/filterParam1value?filterParam2=value&filterParam3=value`

Whenever I change the filters I need to update these values to the URL, the component picks up values from  the URL and calculates the result table.

I need to do this because I need the user to be able to go to the previous filter combination on pressing the back button.

if my code is as below

```js
changeFilters(value1,value2,value3){
  const filterParam1 = value1;
  const filterParam2 = value2;
  const filterParam3 = value3;
  
  updateRouteWithTheseParams();//what do I write here
}
```

Does the component get remounted on updating the route params or just gets rerendered?

Is there a better approach to achieve this?

I am using `"react-router": "^3.0.4"`

Comment: You can probably use browser history and write a function to take params and create a query string from them, then push that to the browser history.

Comment: try `this.props.history.push(\\create your url here)`

Comment: Be aware that react-router v4 dropped support for query strings. You can find discussion and some possible workarounds for [v4 in this GitHug issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4410).